# retry promise with new parmeters

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a promise function, _checkCookie that checks for a cookie and resolves if found and rejects with false if not found.

The function takes one parameter, the cookie name.

I'm now trying to resolve the username by checking multiple different cookies. As in, check for cookie A, if not there check for cookie B and so on.

I'm stuck with getting the checkCookie function to rerun from within its own catch statement. is there a way to have checkCookie try with each potential cookie name without having to recall it in each .catch() block?

```
potentialCookies = ['cookieA','cookieB','cookieC']

 function _checkCookie(cookieName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cname = `${cookieName}=`;
        const ca = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            let c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
                c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(cname) === 0) {
                resolve(c.substring(cname.length, c.length));
            }
        }
        reject(false)
    });
}
```

Here's one option I tried unsuccessfully

```
        _checkCookie("CookieA")
            .catch(e => {
                throw e
            })
            .catch(e => {
                _checkCookie("CookieB")
                console.warn(e, '2')
                throw e
            }).
            catch(e => {
              _checkCookie("CookieC")
                console.warn(e, '3')
                throw e
            })
```

Comment: Why are you using promises at all for a thing that is totally synchronous?

Comment: @Bergi _"Why are you using promises at all for a thing that is totally synchronous?"_ If your assessment of Question is that `Promise` is not necessary to meet requirement why did you post an Answer using `Promise`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to re-`throw` the original error and ignore the result of the `_checkCookie` call. Instead, return that promise you get back, so that the next function in the chain waits for it:

```
_checkCookie("CookieA")
.catch(e => {
    console.warn(e, '2');
    return _checkCookie("CookieB");
})
.catch(e => {
    console.warn(e, '3');
    return _checkCookie("CookieC");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Promise.all()`, handle the errors within `.then()` or `.catch()` to prevent `Promise.all()` from reaching `.catch()`

```
potentialCookies = ['cookieA','cookieB','cookieC']

 function _checkCookie(cookieName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cname = `${cookieName}=`;
        const ca = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            let c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
                c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(cname) === 0) {
                resolve(c.substring(cname.length, c.length));
            }
        }
        reject(false)
    }).then(function(data) {
      return data
    }
    // handle error
    , function(error) {
      console.error(error);
      return error + " no cookie found"
    });
}

Promise.all(potentialCookies.map(_checkCookie))
.then(function(results) {
  console.log(results)
})
```

Comment: "downvote" description? What is the issue with JavaScript at Answer?